# Python sqlite3 query generation

Tags: python, sqlite

Having following:

```
array = ['', 'kujawski=', "'", "select * from symbols where name = '='", ';drop table;', 'fakeone=']
```

I can easly generate following query:

```
//(query, array)
('select count(*) from symbols where  name in (?,?,?,?,?,?)', ('', 'kujawski=', "'", "select * from symbols where name = '='", ';drop table;', 'fakeone='))
```

to generate query which I can put into cursor.execute() function and I'm currently doing it by following code:

```
"select count(*) from table where name in (%s)" % ",".join("?"*len(array)),array
```

And cursor.execute() function return desired output. However problem is when I would like to filter query with AND, for example:

```
select count(*) from table where name in (...) and column5 in (...)
```

I have no idea how to generate query in python which cursor.execute() function will accept it, please help - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with your second `select` statement with the joins.  The first line is what you should pass to `cur.execute()`.  For example:

```
`cur.execute(
    'select count(*) from symbols where  name in (?,?,?,?,?,?)',
    ('', 'kujawski=', "'", "select * from symbols where name = '='", ';drop table symbols;', 'fakeone=')
)`
```

This will also prevent SQL injection attacks, which is what you yourself are trying to take advantage of.

If you want to execute `drop` statements and the like, then you should be using `cur.execute()` to handle that on its own, not as an embedded command within another command like you're trying.

In fact, I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish AT ALL with this.  This is your statement (roughly) after sqlite gets done with it.

```
select
    count(*)
from
    symbols
where
    name in (
        '',
        'kujawski=',
        "'",
        "select * from symbols where name = '='",
        ';drop table symbols;',
        'fakeone=')
```

Comment: Dear @UtahJarhead thank you for the reply, but the problem is that I don't know the size of the array and I would like to generate query accordingly to array size and have two filters in where statement (AND).

Comment: Do you not know what the column names of the filters you want to use?  Just to make sure I understand, you don't know the table data and you don't know what the possible values might be.  That correct?

Comment: Dear @UtahJarhead I know all database schemas because I have created it. I want to automatically generate this part of query "name in (?,?) and something_else in (?,?,?)" and provide arguments for quote marks.